# Sitecore Insert options not working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm fairly new to sitecore and having lots of trouble. I found a couple of articles that show how to add items to the insert context menu of a template, and I was able to get it to work once, on one of my templates. It worked off of the root of the template. But this root has branches under, and when I try to set the insert options for those branches, it does not work.

I did not build this site so I am not sure what is happening.
Is it possible there is some security setting somewhere keeping it from working? Or could it be that they are not linking to individual module items, but perhaps a menu somewhere, and that maybe it is that menu that I need to update?

To make matters worse, I am not sure where I should be assigning these insert options. The articles I've read say to do it on the _standardvalues of the template, but under branches I see the template of the same name and it actually has the branch structure underneath, which is where I actually want the insert to be (under Column 5). I've attached a screenshot if it helps.

http://www.accriva.com/tree.JPG

Answer (score 2):

The insert options for a template are always set on the _standard values of that template.

Branches are not templates. Branches use templates to define a common content structure which content editors need to re create often and therefore it saves the editors time.

To add insert options to your Column template. Either navigate to the template if you know where it is or click on the column 5 node in your branch, look at the quick info section of the item. There you will find a link to the items template. Click on the template link, the template should open. In the left hand menu expand the template so that you can see the __standard values. If you have no standard values then create them. Click on __standard values then select configure in the sitecore ribbon (top menu). Now click on assign within the insert options section and select the templates you wish this template to have as insert options.

Now your column template will have the insert options set correctly. If you dont see them then go back to your column 5 node in your branch, you may have overridden the standard value settings and hence wont see the correct insert options. To ensure your getting the correct insert options from your template, select the column 5 node then in the ribbon click on configure then reset within the insert options section this will reset your insert options to that set in the standard values of your template.

Now if you still don't see the insert option changes that you have made then go back to the column template, select its standard values. Click on assign in the insert options section of the configure tab. In the insert options pop up, look to your left. You will see an option to select insert rules. Click on that and check if you have any insert rules for this template. If you do then find the insert rule item under system/settings/insert rules. Once you have found it select the rule and it will contain a reference to a class within your solution. Use that reference to find the class in your solution and debug that logic, it may be enforcing insert options programmatically.

Comment: Jason, thanks for the assist. I'll see if I can get it to work and report back!

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing out clicking on the template link, the led me to yet another piece of the puzzle which I did not know existed. BUT, when I go to insert options, there is a list of IDs, but they all indicate that the item can not be found. I'm thinking that they have set overrides on the branch or something, but I don't want to reset because I'm afraid I'll really screw something up. It could be that I'm doing it wrong too, I'm checking existing pages to see if they now have insert options after my changes, but would the changes only apply on newly created pages?

Comment: So you found the template and when you look at the standard values you see ids not template names? This means that the insert options were set once but the templates it was set to have been removed. You can leave the Ids for now and add the required templates to the standard values insert options as I suggested above. Also the insert options will automatically apply to all items created by that template past or present unless they have been overridden on the item itself.

Comment: Right, I see a string of characters. I know that the insert options are feeding from somewhere, I just can't figure out where! I'll keep trying...

Comment: Did you find them? As mentioned above. The insert options are either on the item, template or template standard values. They could also be set by an insert rule.

Comment: I can't figure this out. When I add set the insert options, it works only on the item for which it was set directly, but it does not work on content pages based on that template. I'm thinking there is a rule somewhere, but I have been unable to find anything...

Comment: Have you checked out John Wests blogs on the topic, he has other related topics listed at the bottom of this post: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/03/all-about-insert-options-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

Comment: I have.... I'm afraid ASP is just over my head. I'm a PHP guy and none of this makes much sense to me. We have an agency we work with so I'll get them to show me how. Thanks for all of your help. I'll keep reading, maybe I'll figure it out...

Comment: Did you ever get there mate?